# Eclipse: Convert to Maven - unknown packaging: eclipse-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I am trying to convert my Eclipse RCP 3 Product into a Maven Project. 
This is the pom.xml it created:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin</groupId>
   <artifactId>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0.qualifier</version>
   <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>
```

The error message "Project Build Error: Unknown packaging: eclipse-plugin" comes up. I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Maven to **enable** the Tycho **extension** (which registers Tycho’s packaging types):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${tychoVersion}</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

See the [Tycho Reference Card](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card#Enabling_tycho) for details.

You should also get in the habit of defining a `tychoVersion` property, as Tycho will complain if you mix multiple versions of the various Tycho plugins in your build.

Comment: Hello please look at my answer